# Telnet library for java

Tags: java, user-interface, telnet

Is there a library for Java that allows a program to use the Telnet protocol?

There is a website that I would like to connect to using the Telnet protocol and I would like to display the output that I get from that website in a scrolling text field, as well as allow the user to send text to the server.  Are there any easy ways to accomplish this using a Swing GUI?

**Note:** there already is a question with a title quite similar to this one (Java Telnet Library) -- however, this question and that question are asking two entirely different things.

EDIT: I am trying to connect to a server, not a website - specifically, telehack.com.

Comment: You don't use telnet to talk to web-servers, you use the [hypertext transfer protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http).

Comment: telnet = raw TCP. why do you need a library for that?

Comment: Have a look at this. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtelnet/

Comment: I looked at the site, I don't think a telnet library is what you need. The website itself is a browser interface to a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting here: http://javatelnet.org/space/start.

As for the Swing GUI, you should be able to easily pipe text into it from the Telnet server (though you really should use SSH for security purposes).

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid the Apache one. I used it before and I was getting out of order message arriving at the host under heavy load. As the host was a controlling our servers this was pretty damn useless since the commands needed to be precise.

Comment: I believe so. We ended up using some random BSD licensed library that hadn't been updated in like 10 years, but it worked.